# Map local server drive(selected folder) to AWS instance (LOCAL TO CLOUD)

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, smb

So i'm planning to map my local drive to the AWS instance, 
ok why i'm doing this is because i'm having some files in the local server, and the front-end application to download the files is at the AWS cloud server. so by mapping the drive i able to set the virtual directory and set the physical path as the mapped drive at IIS so the application able to download the files.

but whenever i trying to map its failing.

currently i already allow SMB ports at both local server firewall and aws security groups so both of the able to communicate,

current security group configuration that has been allowed :

- port tcp 445, 135, 139
- port udp 137
- port tcp 3389 for rdp
- destination to my server ip (public)

the parameter to map the drive i use is :
  \serverip\drive\directory\

so what configuration/setup i'm missing

Hope anyone can help me

Thank you

Comment: I would tend to recommend against such mapping due to performance reasons, so if you get it going let us know whether it works well! Could you please edit your question to include the configuration of the Security Group associated with the Amazon EC2 instance? Also, with regards to networking -- can you currently RDP into that instance from the local machine?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , hi there, thanks for replying, so i have edited the post as requested, also yes, from my local server, i able to rdp to the cloud.

Comment: What do you mean by "destination to my server ip (public)"? Also, have you configured the Windows Firewall to permit access?

Comment: sorry i mean the "Source" from AWS security group , i input as my server ip . yes i have configured the windows firewall also, i just found that at my instance, i didn't found SMB protocol in the server manager or services. is this the root cause?

Comment: No idea! (I'm not really a Windows person.) You could also test by launching two Windows instances in the same VPC and trying to get them to talk. Then, try it from your local computer.